# How to count items in HTML name array attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, count

I have 3 checkboxes and the user can only select 1 or 2 of them. If the user select 3 checkbox, I will show a message with jQuery saying "You can't select 3 items".

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Walk" name="sports[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="Swim" name="sports[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="Run"  name="sports[]">
```

Is it possible to count items that are inside `sports[]` array?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can get the number checked with `$('input[name="sports[]"]:checked').length;`. You'll still need to wrap that up in a change event handler on your inputs though.

Comment: Do you want to match the number of sports in the array of the attribute `name`? E.g. `name="sports[racquetball, cricket]"`?

Comment: @SvenTheSurfer I just need to count the selected sports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check length of checked items using `:checked` selector in jquery and make it unchecked if 3 of them are selected

```js
$('input[name="sports[]"]:checkbox').change(function() {
    if($('input[name="sports[]"]:checked').length>2)
    {
        alert("You can't select 3 items");
        this.checked=false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="Walk" name="sports[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="Swim" name="sports[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="Run"  name="sports[]">
```

Answer (score 2):

Below solution should work for you

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Walk" name="sports[]" class="myCheckBox">
<input type="checkbox" value="Swim" name="sports[]" class="myCheckBox">
<input type="checkbox" value="Run"  name="sports[]" class="myCheckBox">

$(".myCheckBox").change(function() {
    if($('input[name="sports[]"]:checked').length > 2) {
        //Do your error stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: Since you added a convenient class name, you could also use that in the selector for the `.length`

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of "checked" checkboxes with the name sports[], then throw an error if the count is 3

```
var count = $('input[name="sports[]"]:checked').length;
if(count >=3){ // stop the form submit and do alert messages }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this with jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input^="sports[]"').on('click',function(){
        var total_checked = $('input^="sports[]":checked').length();
        if(total_checked >= 2)
        {
            alert("You can check any two options.");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @SvenTheSurfer, I did not understand.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay: It's not really appropriate site etiquette to ask for answer acceptance like that.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ, sometimes its needed to remind the person because as soon as they get their solution, they move on and does not show courtesy to up vote or accept the answer.

Comment: It's true that users aren't always good about voting, but asking for acceptance so quickly isn't fair to other answerers who may provide a different/better/more in-depth answer later than yourself. I wouldn't worry about a few imaginary internet points. Check out [Dealing with an answer that wasn't accepted (maybe because a user is a newbie on Stack Overflow)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-on) for some community thoughts on this..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it possible to count items that are inside sports[] array. You can map over the tags parsing as you go.

```js
let input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
let result = [...input].map(x => JSON.parse(x.name.replace('sports', '')))
let count = result.map(x => x.length);
console.log('the arrays', result);
console.log('the counts within', count);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="Walk" name="sports[1,2,3,4]">
<input type="checkbox" value="Swim" name="sports[5,6,7,8]">
<input type="checkbox" value="Run" name="sports[10,11,12,13]">
```